# Creating mark-up for non-retina display on Mac Book Pro with Retina

Tags: html, sass, compass-sass, retina-display

I've just bought a Mac Book Pro with Retina display because i have to optimise graphics on sites for it. I am generating two sprites with compass, one of them is double sized.

So i wonder how could check the website on Retina display but avoiding media queries for it, without double size images, you see what i mean?

What is the easiest way? Should i change resolution or just disable media queries to have a look?

Comment: I would just disable the specific media queries.